# Primefaces datatable: How create two colums of the same datatable?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a datatable with `max 60 rows` and I would like create full page datatable. So if I have less then `30 rows` create datatable in one half but if I have more than `30 rows` create `30 rows` in one half and the rest of rows in second half of the page.

Comment: how create this datatable

Comment: USe paginator.It has number of rows to be displayed option.